# Command button action not called

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have the following situation:

```
<h:form>
<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
    <p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Login" ajax="false"
                        action="#{login.loginAction}" />
</h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

When I click the button, the method loginAction(), from my bean, is executed.

If I have:

```
<h:form>

    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">

        <h:outputLabel for="username" value="#{labels.UserName}" />
        <p:inputText value="#{login.username}" id="username"
                                required="true" />

        <p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Login" ajax="false"
                        action="#{login.loginAction}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

In this situation,when I press the login button the method loginAction() is not called, and I don't understand why. The setter for the username is called, but the loginAction no.

I am using JSF 2.0, Primefaces 3.3.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use

```
<h:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Login" ajax="false"
                        action="#{login.loginAction}" />
```

the method loginAction is called.

I will use h:commandButton instead of p:commandButton.

Comment: `h:commandButton` has no `ajax` attribute, you can omit it. If you don't embed an `f:ajax` the h:commandButton is a non-ajax button and triggers a full form submit.

Comment: Thanks man! really, JSF should log this in console when in development state.

Comment: Just like PrimeFaces `p:commandButton` with `ajax="false"`. Should not be any difference

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you do not get an error in your console either right? If that's the case, i would suggest add `<p:messages autoUpdate="true" />` just inside your form to see if there is some validation error or something.